# Another Inheritance Question

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, class, extends

From a quick Google search and a the wikipedia article on Multiple Inheritance, which quotes:

> Multiple inheritance refers to a feature of some object-oriented programming languages in which a class can inherit behaviors and features from more than one superclass. This contrasts with single inheritance, where a class may inherit from at most one superclass.

I understand that PHP doesn't allow multiple inheritance. What I can't find a clear answer on, however, is whether it allows more than one class to extend a superclass. Example:

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}
class c extends a {}
```

In terms of what I'm trying to do, I'm making an RPG and want a 'generic' character class to include all the methods and properties that make the template of a character. Then I want classes to include specifics for each type of character (warrior, mage, etc), such as stats modifiers and special attacks.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. The entire purpose of inheritance is that multiple children can inherit common functionality from a parent.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I wasn't sure with all the talk of multiple inheritance, haha.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multiple classes can extend the same class, per your code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is the foundation of OOP. It's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any class can extend a base class. In your example, it just isn't possible for class c to extend both a and b.

Answer (score 0):

So in an adjusted example like the one above

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}
class c extends b {}
```

c could not get to properties of a ?